# densely packed construction/constructions

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In the following sentence, should "construction" or "constructions" be used?

> The mere fact that they are cities, with densely packed **construction**, places their populations at greater risk from natural disasters, including those expected to be made worse by climate change.

https://www.reuters.com/article/us-climate-cities-idUKTRE7367DH20110407

Comment: *Construction* is used in an uncountable sense here, as a general phenomenon.

Comment: Does't it make more sense to use "constructions" in the sense of "buildings" in that context?

Comment: No, because *constructions* is not a common synonym for *buildings*.

Comment: But the countable singular "construction" is a synonym for "bulding": The summer house was a simple wooden construction.

Comment: I'm wondering why the plural form doesn't work in the OP example.

Comment: *Construction* is not an exact synonym for *building*; it refers more to the act of building, or how something was built.  You would never say "I live in a construction."

Answer (score 2):

"construction" is better here. "constructions" would be interpretable as an abstract word for "buildings" or "infrastructure", but it would be very unexpected.

Here "construction" can mean "an ongoing process of changing the infrastructure" or "the general collection of things that have been built". The former doesn't seem to work very well with "densely packed", but it's possible the author meant "densely packed construction *projects*".

The alternative is to understand it as "a layout, especially regarding buildings, that is densely packed".

Comment: Is "buildings" a viable alternative in the OP example?

Comment: @Apollyon Yup. Even better would be "infrastructure" to capture more than just the buildings, but also roads, bike lanes, subways, playgrounds, etc.